# Error when sending html source from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following to encode the html source of a ckeditor in a web application.

```
var updateString = app.getValue('wysiwygHomePage');
var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(updateString);
alert(encodedString);
app.httpRequest("www.xxxx.com/techy/savealldata.php", "GET", function(data, error, httpResponse){
    alert(data);
}, 
{
  "updateType":"homePage","updateString":encodedString}, "String", {}, {});
}
```

Then at the PHP end I am using :

```
<?php 
$updateType = $_GET["updateType"];
$updateString = $_GET["updateString"];
$updateString2 = urldecode($updateString);
echo 'success here '.$updateType .'   '.$updateString2 ;
?>
```

I am adding some coloured tex and the html source for this is:

```
<p>
<span style="color: rgb(255, 140, 0);">123</span><br />
&nbsp;
</p>
<p>
```

This works okay until I cut and paste more than 32 times.

I then just get `error` returned from the PHP call.

I presume there are to many chars arriving at the PHP end ???

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Mr WARBY.

**UPDATED PHP Code.**

```
<?php 
include 'dbdata.php';

$updateType = $_POST["updateType"];
$updateString = $_POST["updateString"];
$updateString2 = urldecode($updateString);


//echo 'success here '.$updateType .'   '.$updateString2 ;

if($updateType === 'homePage')
{
$query5 =  "UPDATE pageText SET HTML= "."'".$updateString2."'"." WHERE ID = 12";
//echo $query5;
       echo 'Home Page Updated 2';
mysql_query($query5);
}

if($updateType === 'instructionPage')
{
  $query5 =  "UPDATE pageText SET HTML= "."'".$updateString2."'"." WHERE ID = 13";
  echo 'Instruction Page Updated 2';
  mysql_query($query5);
}

if($updateType === 'FAQPage')
{
  $query5 =  "UPDATE pageText SET HTML= "."'".$updateString2."'"." WHERE ID = 14";
  echo 'FAQ Page Updated';
  mysql_query($query5);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a GET request? GET requests have a length limit (which may or may not be the problem here), and don't semantically match up with "saving" something. Use a POST request and see if the same problem still happens

Comment: Hi @ian. I have change to POST and can get 40+ rows of the above text and also save it into the database. However when I try to save a more complicated HTML source the update in the database fails. I have added my updated PHP code above.

Comment: Probably help to add `or die(mysql_error())` when you're debugging. That being said, why are you using a deprecated extension in (presumably) new code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables in play here.  You need to change your debugging strategy.  Instead of testing end to end each time try isolating each component.

In Javascript, call "app.getValue('wysiwygHomePage')", encode the string, decode the string, and put it right back in the editor.  Do that in a loop until you can determine if the client-side is mangling anything.

If not, try encoding a complicated string in Javascript, sending it to a PHP script that decodes/re-encodes and echos it back.  Do that in a loop several times.

If you still haven't found the problem try making a PHP script that takes a complicated string, INSERTS it, SELECTs it, UPDATEs it in a loop to see if you database encoding or escaping is affecting it.

If at any point you find the string changing when it shouldn't you've probably found your problem.

Comment: Hi @billy, I setup encoding and decodeing and getting data back from PHP. It all displayed okay in the application. So I echoed the update error and it showed an error near <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times, serif;"> So I manually changed 'times new roman' to "times new roman" and it updated ok. So it looks like the update fails when seeing ''. How do I address this issue ?

Comment: When you say 'getting back from PHP' do you also mean from your database?

Comment: Also you should consider encoding your data before inserting it to prevent a myriad of problems (http://bobby-tables.com/).  Base64 works well (http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).